Path problem with subfiles, and fontspec
I have the project with the following structure:
fonts/
   times.ttf
   timesbd.ttf
   timesbi.ttf
   timesi.ttf
sections/
   section1.tex
main.tex

My main.tex contains:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{times}[
    Ligatures = {Rare},
    Path = \currfileabsdir/fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    BoldFont = *bd,
    ItalicFont = *i,
    BoldItalicFont = *bi]

\begin{document}
This is from main.
\subfile{sections/section1}
\end{document}

and my sections/section1.tex contains:
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
This is from section 1.
\end{document}

When compiling with XeLaTeX from main.tex, everything works fine.
But when I compile from sections/section1.tex, I get a Package fontspec Error: The font "times" cannot be found..
I totally get that the problem comes from the way subfiles works with paths (hence the fix I've been trying to do with currfile) but I can't figure out a solution. Also, I cannot use absolute system paths since I'm working on Overleaf (collaborative project). Does anyone have an idea?
PS: I'm using local font files because I need a specific version of Times New Roman (7.1). That's why I'm not using the package times.

you would not use the times package with xetex in any case but Times New Roman is installed at overleaf are you sure that version is not suitable?

I confirm, ligatures and smallcaps do not work when I use \setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures = {Rare}] instead.

OK, thanks for confirming

Use the command \subfix; for details see the documentation of the subfiles package.
    Path = \subfix{fonts/},

The entire code of main.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{times}[
    Ligatures = {Rare},
    Extension = .ttf,
    Path = \subfix{fonts/},% <<<<
    BoldFont = *bd,
    ItalicFont = *i,
    BoldItalicFont = *bi]

\begin{document}
This is from main.
\subfile{sections/section1}
\end{document}

